# Python multithreading and multiprocessing together

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Is it possible to spawn multiple processes from a single thread? Or is it a proper design to implement?

My code sample is -

```
def run_all_tasks(self):
    for platform in self._platforms:
        task_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=self._run_task_list, args=(
                self._get_tasks(),platform,))
        taskset_threads.append(task_thread)

    for taskset_thread in taskset_threads:
        taskset_thread.start()

    for taskset_thread in taskset_threads:
        taskset_thread.join() 

def _run_task_list(self, tasklist, platform):
    try:
        test_case_name = task.__class__.__name__

        try:
            test_case_name = task._get_test_case_name()
        except:
            test_case_name = task.__class__.__name__
            pass

        max_runtime = task.get_max_runtime()

        manager = Manager()
        self._shared_mem = manager.dict()

        for task in tasklist:
            task_proc = Process(
                target=self.proc_setup,
                args=(task, self, self._shared_mem))


            task_proc.start()
            task_proc.join(max_runtime)
```

This works however, sometimes it gives following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\wor\lib\TaskSet.py", line 430, in _run_task_list
    if "warning" in self._shared_mem:
  File "<string>", line 2, in __contains__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 755, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 742, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 167, in Client
    c = PipeClient(address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 387, in PipeClient
    win32.WaitNamedPipe(address, 1000)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This can also be seen on linux platform.

Comment: Don't see why not. I am working in a threaded server that starts processes. Just don't mix up the libraries since both multithreading and multiprocessing have exact same names in them.

Comment: Thanks.. How about replacing thread with another process. Process which will spawn another process.?

Comment: Don't see why not. Keeping tabs on the whole thing at run time is going to be a challenge though.